# Ajax UpdatePanel not working in IIS

Tags: asp.net, ajax, iis, asp.net-ajax

Does anyone have any idea what this means? -:

```
Type.registerNamespace('Sys');Sys.Res={"argumentInteger":"Value must be an integer.","invokeCalledTwice":"Cannot call invoke more than once.","webServiceFailed":"The server method \u0027{0}\u0027 failed with the following error: {1}","argumentType":"Object cannot be converted to the required type.","argumentNull":"Value cannot be null.","scriptAlreadyLoaded":"The script \u0027{0}\u0027 has been referenced multiple times. If referencing Microsoft AJAX scripts explicitly, set the MicrosoftAjaxMode property of the ScriptManager to Explicit.","scriptDependencyNotFound":"The script \u0027{0}\u0027 failed to load because it is dependent on script \u0027{1}\u0027.","formatBadFormatSpecifier":"Format specifier was invalid.","requiredScriptReferenceNotIncluded":"\u0027{0}\u0027 requires that you have included a script reference to \u0027{1}\u0027.","webServiceFailedNoMsg":"The server method \u0027{0}\u0027 failed.","argumentDomElement":"Value must be a DOM element.","invalidExecutorType":"Could not create a valid Sys.Net.WebRequestExecutor from: {0}.","cannotCallBeforeResponse":"Cannot call {0} when responseAvailable is false.","actualValue":"Actual value was {0}.","enumInvalidValue":"\u0027{0}\u0027 is not a valid value for enum {1}.","scriptLoadFailed":"The script \u0027{0}\u0027 could not be loaded.","parameterCount":"Parameter count mismatch.","cannotDeserializeEmptyString":"Cannot deserialize empty string.","formatInvalidString":"Input string was not in a correct format.","invalidTimeout":"Value must be greater than or equal to zero.","cannotAbortBeforeStart":"Cannot abort when executor has not started.","argument":"Value does not fall within the expected range.","cannotDeserializeInvalidJson":"Cannot deserialize. The data does not correspond to valid JSON.","invalidHttpVerb":"httpVerb cannot be set to an empty or null string.","nullWebRequest":"Cannot call executeRequest with a null webRequest.","eventHandlerInvalid":"Handler was not added through the Sys.UI.DomEvent.addHandler method.","cannotSerializeNonFiniteNumbers":"Cannot serialize non finite numbers.","argumentUndefined":"Value cannot be undefined.","webServiceInvalidReturnType":"The server method \u0027{0}\u0027 returned an invalid type. Expected type: {1}","servicePathNotSet":"The path to the web service has not been set.","argumentTypeWithTypes":"Object of type \u0027{0}\u0027 cannot be converted to type \u0027{1}\u0027.","cannotCallOnceStarted":"Cannot call {0} once started.","badBaseUrl1":"Base URL does not contain ://.","badBaseUrl2":"Base URL does not contain another /.","badBaseUrl3":"Cannot find last / in base URL.","setExecutorAfterActive":"Cannot set executor after it has become active.","paramName":"Parameter name: {0}","nullReferenceInPath":"Null reference while evaluating data path: \u0027{0}\u0027.","cannotCallOutsideHandler":"Cannot call {0} outside of a completed event handler.","cannotSerializeObjectWithCycle":"Cannot serialize object with cyclic reference within child properties.","format":"One of the identified items was in an invalid format.","assertFailedCaller":"Assertion Failed: {0}\r\nat {1}","argumentOutOfRange":"Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.","webServiceTimedOut":"The server method \u0027{0}\u0027 timed out.","notImplemented":"The method or operation is not implemented.","assertFailed":"Assertion Failed: {0}","invalidOperation":"Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.","breakIntoDebugger":"{0}\r\n\r\nBreak into debugger?"};
```

Or this? -:

```
"PRM_UnknownToken":"Unknown token: \u0027{0}\u0027.","PRM_MissingPanel":"Could not find UpdatePanel with ID \u0027{0}\u0027. If it is being updated dynamically then it must be inside another UpdatePanel.","PRM_ServerError":"An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: {0}","PRM_ParserError":"The message received from the server could not be parsed. Common causes for this error are when the response is modified by calls to Response.Write(), response filters, HttpModules, or server trace is enabled.\r\nDetails: {0}","PRM_TimeoutError":"The server request timed out.","PRM_ParserErrorDetails":"Error parsing near \u0027{0}\u0027.","PRM_CannotRegisterTwice":"The PageRequestManager cannot be initialized more than once."};
```

I get these errors in the debugger when I inspect elements. UpdatePanels are not working at all. I'm using AjaxToolkit. Using IIS 7.5

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would check your firewall logs to see if the client is being blocked.

The only time I got this error was when my firewall was blocking the post-back because it exceeded the `parameter length limit`.

You may find if you took out the update panel and all the Ajax functionality, that you would get a "Page cannot be found" message from your firewall, but the Ajax functionality "hides" the error from the user, so only shows up in the debugger.

**The solution** for me was to raise the parameter length limit for the `__EVENTVALIDATION` perameter (to 1600 in my case). Now, it may be a different limit or perameter that would need to be changed in your case, but if you find that the firewall is blocking it, it should tell you why.

*"If all else fails, check your firewall."*

I know it's a little bit of a late post, but maybe this will save someone else the week of debugging and research I had to go through.

I hope it helps!